# Strange surging and like it's going to stall, hesitant whilst idling

Tags: engine, noise, peugeot, lean

I have been having an issue with my Peugeot 207 (2008 model) 1.6L VTI petrol engine.

The cam cover was replaced by the garage but hasn't fixed the problem. I have lost faith in them. I have managed to record and upload an example of the noise it makes, but I now realise that when you (the reader) listen to this you can't tell the noises apart because there's just too much noise - you might be able to pick something out though:

http://youtu.be/q0mc9aaSaHw

Anyway, a good revving of the accelerator cleared it to a more normal sound this time. But something is not right.

When it's idling the engine becomes hesitant and it behaves like it's about to stall. The garage thought it was because a break in the cam cover was letting too much air in, which is what the OBD was suggesting (O2 sensor stuck lean, both before and after the Cat).

Also, now first gear is making a louder noise than usual. I'd describe as a bit like what I imagine it sounds like when a cat is being strangled. 2nd gear behaves like first, 3rd like second and so on.

Since the new cam cover has been put on the behaviour has gotten worse, but at least the oil has stopped dripping.

My thoughts are:

Throttle body: Give it a good clean and fit back again.

Full oil change and filter change (overdue anyway).

Maybe the gear box?

Maybe the cat converter?

I'm clutching at straws now.

Comment: I'm hearing so much noise it's hard to discriminate on what you are trying to point out. It sounds to me like the *entire top end is dry* (not getting oil). There is soooo much noise there ... wow. I'm leaving this as a comment, hoping that someone else might have more experience with Peugeots. Maybe they all sound like this? I hope not, but on the other hand, I hope someone can discount what I'm thinking.

Comment: Fair point. I'll do an oil and filter change first.

Comment: It is impossible to determine what noise is what from the video, the audio media is swamping everything.

Comment: Thanks guys. Have edited the question to down-play the video and try and focus on the problem a bit more.

Comment: Was looking at your question again. The O2's can be stuck lean for many different reasons. The main reason I've seen is due to either exhaust manifold leak or unmetered air entering the system (air entering the system after the metering apparatus, which is a MAF ... not sure on Peugeots.) I'd check for leaks in exhaust up stream of the O2 sensors or leaks in the intake tract after the MAF (if it has a MAF) or after the throttle body if it doesn't.

Comment: We got rid of the car in the end. Took it to a few places, eventually to a Peugeot specialist and even they could not track it down properly and wanted to fit new sensors and do other work that just didn't sound logical. I hear the throttle bodies on these Peugeots are notorious at getting clogged up but I couldn't seem to convince anyone else to spend some time in that area. It all just become uneconomical, so we got rid. But I'm absolutely convinced it's a throttle body problem.

Comment: That sucks, these engines on most Peugeot of that size/era tend to always sound a bit tappy. Don't suppose it matters now but I'm not sure how the garage got away with attributing this to the cam cover. Sounds like a vacuum leak or throttle body. That whining noise is interesting too, my friend has a 207 and its made a very similar noise for over a year with many miles. Either these weren't maintained properly when new or just aren't built well.

Answer (score 3):

Just because the OBD says it's an O2 sensor, doesn't necessarily make it so.  Some diagnostic codes are pretty simple & to-the-point.  But, the logic baked into the computer also has rules like "if this, and also that, but not this other thing, then blame [widget]."  But the engineers who designed it all didn't necessarily cover perfectly all the bad states for every combination of sensor and range of sensor readings, so sometimes a combination of things can lead the computer to diagnose incorrectly / fuzzily.  It is that type of situation where a mechanic's experience with a particular make & model becomes particularly valuable.

Since you said it wanted to stall at idle: if I had seen this question when it still mattered to you, as a first pass I would have suggested that you clean the MAF sensor (with a special cleaner designed for that purpose!) and then reset the ECU.  I make this recommendation because it solved my own similar problem (stalling at idle, although in my case the 'wrong' OBDII code that my Mitsubishi was giving was P0300 (Random/Multiple Cylinder Misfire.)  In general you want to start with the simplest/cheapest explanation, and work your way from there.  MAF cleaner is US$10, tops.

Your transmission noises were likely a separate issue altogether, and it would have been best to post a separate question for it.

*(I am not expecting this answer to be accepted; I'm just contributing it in the hopes that it helps someone else out in the future.)*

Answer (score 0):

My Nissan march started surging at fast speeds ,sometimes so hard they locked my seat belt and feeling like it was running out of petrol.(was also using a hell of a lot more petrol than it usually does) and when going slow it would start vibrating and nearly stalling(i hated traffic lights in it) twice it actually did completely stall. and when i would put my foot on the gas it would only realize about 7 seconds later! (stressful in a big city)....anyway i got scared of driving it in fear i wouldn't be able to re start it one day in a busy intersection so i took it to a garage and he took his best guess and replaced all of the spark plugs and wires. i thought it would be fixed!,then he said as i left that if it still does it that it would be the distributor...ugh....anyway you guessed it,it did it all the way home even worse than before and it was a two hour drive! :-(...i was pretty upset! AND to top it off i used it to do a quick errand and it completely turned off at a green light and wouldn't start until the 6th attempt! i drove straight to an auto electrician and explained it.left it with them arrived back in two days and it is PERFECT! all fixed. They put a new throttle body in it and it drives like new. it feels good to trust it at the traffic lights now lol.

Comment: Nice story :-).